# Background of UIView shifts image down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have changed my default image (so instead of the black loading screen its a custom image). And i want this same image to be the background on my first UIView. I have made the navigation bar on this UIView hidden. However, when I set a background image of the view to the image of size 480x320, the one used in the default loading screen, the image is shifted downwards. 
Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this problem? 
In other words, I want the background image to fill its normal size (aka screen size 320x480). 
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Set your view.frame to:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

I think its using:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

Now =)

Comment: Thanks for the help, just before you posted this i shifted the image to start at y co-ordinate -20, and this seemed to do the trick. Thanks anyway man.

Comment: That 20px is the status bar - your Default.png should be 480 tall, your main view's image should be 460 (assuming you leave the status bar displaying) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well. I did not hide/show the navigation bar. Instead, in IB for the ViewController which is shown after the Default.png splash page, I enabled the "Wants Full Screen" option on the Attributes Inspector. This stopped my identical default image from shifting downwards once the initial view controller became active.